# How to define selected column names while reading html in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there is way to use custom column names example `col_names` i have below where i have 42 column names and i need these 3 only, can i define them while reading html.

### Reading HTML File:

```
df = pd.read_html(file.text, use_cols=con_names)
```

The above using `col_names` doesn't work.

### Custom Selected column names:

```
col_names = [ 'col1', 'col4', 'col14' ]
```

### What i tried and Working for me as a Work around:

One way i can use directly as below ...

```
print(df[['col1', 'col4', 'col14']])
```

Answer (score 1):

[read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) doesn't support 'use_cols'. A quick workaround is:

```
df_2 = df[['col1', 'col4', 'col14']]
```

Comment: True Alex, that's what i'm using.